# How do I get input from the console in Nim?

Tags: console, console-application, nim-lang

I'm new to Nim, but it appears that there is no way to get input from the console in a similar way to `input()` in python or `Console.ReadLine()` in dotnet.

I want execution of my code to pause, wait for input, then on pressing enter to continue (just like input in other langs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh no never mind found it:

```
var consoleInput = readLine(stdin);
```

Comment: The semicolon is optional by the way :)
Also you can do it like `stdin.readLine()` too.

Comment: ah nice thanks :)

coming from C# i prefer the semicolons

Comment: Also, linenoise for more advanced features (history, completion...) is included in the standard lib.